# c pointer for struct causes segment fault while doing

Tags: c, pointers, memset

I get a segment fault while it comes to the memset，i've looked anywhere can't know why?Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
typedef struct Ircsend1_struct{
  char type;
  char name[32];
}ircsend1_struct;

ircsend1_struct *ircpack;

char *pBuffer;
ircpack = (ircsend1_struct *)pBuffer;
memset(ircpack,0x00,sizeof(ircsend1_struct));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your pointer is not initialized, maybe you mean

```
ircsend1_struct irpack;
char *pBuffer = &irpack;

memset(pBuffer, 0, sizeof(ircsend1_struct));
```

Comment: You are right.I've done what you write and problem solved.(ircsend1_struct) *ircpack is not initialized and causes segmentfault while memset.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment

```
ircpack = (ircsend1_struct *)pBuffer;
```

is wrong. `pBuffer` is uninitialized. `ircpack` is pointing at unknown location. Therefore, the statement

```
memset(ircpack,0x00,sizeof(ircsend1_struct));
```

will invoke undefined behavior.